# JQuery Numeric Input Mask Allow dot "." character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I have the following code that is use to add a mask to input values. The problem that i have is that except the numeric values i want to **allow** also the **"."** character. The "." character is generated by the plugin but i only want "," so the "." is added by the user.

```js
$('.numericMask').mask("#,##0.00", {
  reverse: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input class="numericMask" type="text" />
```

Comment: you need like this `1,000.00` right?

Comment: @AashifAhamed yes but the dot character should be inserted by the user

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.numericMask').mask("Z", {
                                   translation: {
      'Z': {
        pattern: /[0-9,.]/, recursive: true
      }}});
```

you can do like this .but you need to manually insert comma too.

Comment: thanks but i need something to generate the "." manually and the "," dynamically, not just an input that allows numbers, "," and "."